# MacBook Pro 2009 15” Recovery Mode non existant OSX 10.5.8

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade, internet-recovery

I have a number of issues with a MacBook 2009 15” running Leopard.I wish to upgrade to El Capitan if possible. Do I alter the computer time and date so it corresponds with the download as I can remember from past experience on an iMac I had to do just that. I used Internet Recovery but <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> doesn't seem to show it just goes straight to the front login page, perhaps Leopard doesn't have that function. I don't have the original Leopard startup disks for this model only a 2009 MacBook 13” which probably won't work. If someone could give me a guide on what exactly I should do it would be most appreciated.

Secondly, I have a blue/white vertical bar on the center left of the screen. It doesn't show up when I connect to an external monitor.

MacBook Pro 2009 4 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

If you have another mac, donwload High Sierra, which is the newest version compatible with 2009 iMacs, create a bootable disk and follow Apple's instructions on how to reinstall macOS.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper I will give that shot...

Comment: And if you get an error that there is a problem with the newly downloaded installer. Set the Macs clock back a couple of years and try again. As that is simply an expired certificate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most older Macs didn't come with Recovery Mode partitions (as these can take up a fair bit of space), and instead came with [optical disc](https://cdn.instructables.com/F6Q/HXT0/FQPTT3LF/F6QHXT0FQPTT3LF.LARGE.jpg?auto=webp&frame=1&fit=bounds) or [USB reinstallation medias](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Apple_USB_drive-640x360.jpg) for MacBook Airs without DVD drives. I think, later on, when people stopped being used to storing physical media and probably kept running into "I need to install OS X but I lost/sold/threw away all those DVDs," that's when Apple started including an internal Recovery Mode (Command-R) and an internet-available Internet Recovery Mode (Command-Option-R).

If you updated to a newer version of OS X, it would have likely installed this recovery partition. I had a 2008 MacBook (Polycarbonate) with OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. That's when I learned Recovery Mode didn't exist once upon a time. When I got a 10.7.3 Lion DVD off Amazon, it installed a Recovery Mode partition, and Command-R magically started working. (Internet Recovery Mode didn't, I imagine this is more built into the machine itself, like the EFI or ROM, than into the OS X installation.)

Apple also started including these partitions by default when they shipped machines without discs. However, since your machine is from a time where discs were still standard, and you've never installed a newer version by the sounds of it, this partition is still missing and it is still assuming you've got Ye OS X Install DVD of Olde.

You're probably going to have to download an old OS X installer and jump through a few extra hoops, since 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) is the latest version that even a version as old as El Capitan supports installing on top of. I would suggest OS X Mountain Lion, as I've found old DMGs that still work, and it's within the same time period of Leopard. Install that, then you can install [OS X El Capitan (official)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886) on top of that by launching the PKG that downloads from that Apple page.

El Capitan needs components within your existing installation to install on top of, or it can't work. This is why an intermediary version (like Mountain Lion as suggested here) is needed. It adds a while to the install time, and it's annoying to have to jump through these extra steps, but it's needed nonetheless.

You can Google around for a copy of OS X Mountain Lion that you can download, or you can ask a friend who purchased Snow Leopard, Lion or Mountain Lion from the Mac App Store as they would be able to download it still, from their Purchased tab. Just set the UNIX time code back before you start the installation, as the original certificate has long expired. 
Here's a Google Search string to get you started (paste into search bar):

`"OS X" install download "DMG"`

Comment: Thanks Wynter A clear and precise narrative....:)